# Android make ShapeDrawable match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-shape

I am trying to create a colored Circle and assign it to an ImageView for my GridView.

Here is my code:

```
ImageView ivColor;

ivColor = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
ivColor.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));         

ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
shape.getPaint().setColor(color[i]);
shape.setIntrinsicWidth(128);
shape.setIntrinsicHeight(128);

ivColor.setImageDrawable(shape);
```

For now, i am setting the ShapeDrawable height and width as 128px manually. Is there a way to assign the ShapeDrawable a value of "match_parent" just like i can do with the ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line

```
ivColor.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

to

```
ivColor.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

**Edit:**

In addition, set the you have to run `setScaleType()` for the `ImageView`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

You should try `CENTER_CROP`, `CENTER_FILL` or `FIT_CENTRE` depending on your need.

Comment: Well, i did also try MATCH_PARENT for the ivColor and i should keep it (i will edit question). The issue is i need to also set MATCH_PARENT for the ShapeDrawable also in order to fill the grid space.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ShapeDrawable` as the background for the `ImageView`. Background always fills the `View` so you'll get what you're trying to achieve.

```
ivColor.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
```

or

```
ivColor.setBackground(shape); // Api level 16+
```